# UnicodDecodeError in Binary files

Tags: python, python-3.x, binaryfiles

I've written a small sample code to try out pickle module. Faced UnicodeDecodeError in the pickle.load() statement. Writing encoding='utf-8' also has no effect.
Here's the code

```
import pickle

class NewOne:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "None"
        self.age = 0

    def entries(self):
        self.name = input("Name: ")
        self.age = input("Age: ")

obj1 = NewOne()
for i in range(3):
    obj1.entries()
    pickle.dump(obj1, open("Details", "ab"))

for j in range(3):
    obj = pickle.load(open("Details",))

    if obj.age == 18:
        print("Name: "+obj.name)
```

Comment: I don't get any `UnicodeDecodeError` on Python 2.7 (replacing `input` with `raw_input`). BTW, your `pickle.load()` loads the first object in the file every time because you open the file in every iteration of the loop.

Comment: I'm getting the error using PyCharm. So what can be done to read the next object each time ? I thought it would work like it does in C++.

Comment: Well, try it outside of PyCharm and see if you still get it.

Comment: Trying it out on repl.it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with your code is, that you are appending to the end of the same file every time you run the script, but loading the first three objects later on.

Actually, it's worse than that; You *should* be loading the first three objects, but in fact you are only loading the first one each time because you open the file anew in every iteration of your `pickle.load()`

It may be that there is an error at the beginning of your file, and you are simply hitting this every time because you are loading the first object in the file. You could try deleting your `Details` file and see if you still get the error.

The following code will create a new `details` file each time, write three objects to it, and then load those three objects back in.

```
import pickle

class NewOne:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "None"
        self.age = 0

    def entries(self):
        self.name = raw_input("Name: ")
        self.age = raw_input("Age: ")

obj1 = NewOne()

# Open file for writing. The `with` context manager will automatically close 
# it at the end of the loop
with open("Details", "wb") as myfile:
    for i in range(3):
        obj1.entries()
        pickle.dump(obj1, myfile)

# Re-open the file for reading
with open("Details",) as myfile:
    for j in range(3):
        obj = pickle.load(myfile)

        if obj.age == '18':
            print("Name: "+obj.name)
```